# How to make custom link for some tag pages in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have some tag pages which I want to modify urls for. For example, I have a page *".../tag/tag-1"* and I want to change it to, for example *".../projects/area/tag-1"*.

I want to do the same with tag-2 and tag-3, while tag-4 and tag-5 remain with default *".../tag/tag-4"* links. Is it possible to do this without redirects, new taxonomies, and hopefully so that both types of links (default and new types) show the tag page for these specific tags?

Maybe something like making a new page which displays the same content as the one with default tag link, or a page template which loads archive template by page slug or custom field?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the settings>Permalinks and change the way of linking

If you are using Gutenberg you can change the URL slug in Permalink From The Post Panel

So basically you need to go to the Permalinks, then change to the format you want, then go to the Tag/Categories or whatever and change the slug there, and you'll get needed link

also you can search for some SEO plugins that could help you

Comment: Thanks, but that'll work for all tags/catgories, and I need a link change or content copy only for some of them.

Comment: I see, in this case, you probably would need to create costume taxonomies/posts and register them to separate these two tags options :( you can use CPT UI plugin for easier register

Answer (score 0):

To change your bases of tags and categories, go to your admin dashboard, and then go to Settings > Permalinks:

Under the Optional section, change the existing bases by the ones you want and click Save Changes.

Your bases are now modified according to the needs of your site.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work for this case, as I need to change links for some tags, not all of them, or to copy the content of some archive-tag pages, not all of them.

Comment: You can create pages and copy content and then with redirect plugin you can redirect that tags to your pages

Comment: That's my option is nothing else works basically.